# Error in gseapy.gsea (python): assert len(dat) > 1

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run GSEA on my samples (n=3) and I keep getting this error and I don’t understand why.

Error:

Run GSEA
----> 2 gsea = gseapy.gsea(data=gsea_df_HDM, # the processed data matrix,
3                  gene_sets=gene_sets, #pathways DataFrame converted to a dictionary
4                  cls=gsea_df_condition["Condition"], # the metadata column
5                  permutation_type='phenotype',
6                  min_size=2, # minimum number of compounds in a pathway for it to be tested
7                  permutation_num=100, # reduce number to speed up test
8                  outdir=None,  # do not write output to disk
9                  method='signal_to_noise', # Ranking metric
10                  threads=4, seed= 7)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python_3104/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gseapy/**init**.py:150, in gsea(data, gene_sets, cls, outdir, min_size, max_size, permutation_num, weighted_score_type, permutation_type, method, ascending, threads, figsize, format, graph_num, no_plot, seed, verbose, *arg, **kwarg)
128     threads = kwarg["processes"]
130 gs = GSEA(
131     data,
132     gene_sets,
(...)
148     verbose,
149 )
--> 150 gs.run()
152 return gs
...
--> 265 assert len(dat) > 1
266 # filtering out gene sets and build gene sets dictionary
267 gmt = self.load_gmt(gene_list=dat.index.values, gmt=self.gene_sets)

Input:
Run GSEA

```
gsea = gseapy.gsea(data=gsea_df_HDM, # the processed data matrix,  
                 gene_sets=gene_sets, #pathways DataFrame converted to a dictionary
                 cls=gsea_df_condition["Condition"], # the metadata column
                 permutation_type='phenotype',
                 min_size=2, # minimum number of compounds in a pathway for it to be tested
                 permutation_num=100, # reduce number to speed up test
                 outdir=None,  # do not write output to disk
                 method='signal_to_noise', # Ranking metric
                 threads=4, seed= 7)
```

Data info
gsea_df_HDM:
type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
shape:(578, 6) ( rows = protein uniport IDs, columns = samples)

gsea_df_condition["Condition"]:
type: pandas.core.series.Series
len: 6
print:
HDM_CD101_neg_grouped_1    HDM_CD101_neg_grouped
HDM_CD101_neg_grouped_2    HDM_CD101_neg_grouped
HDM_CD101_neg_grouped_3    HDM_CD101_neg_grouped
HDM_CD101_pos_grouped_1    HDM_CD101_pos_grouped
HDM_CD101_pos_grouped_2    HDM_CD101_pos_grouped
HDM_CD101_pos_grouped_3    HDM_CD101_pos_grouped
Name: Condition, dtype: object

I've tried changing gsea_df_condition["Condition"] into a list, Ive confirmed its shape, I tried pulling the metadata from another table, etc. I've confirmed the length is >1

Ive tried looking at the source code to better understand what the error is coming from, but Im not advanced enough to figure it out.

I've also run it with an example dataset and it works. My inputs are in the same format so Im not sure whats wrong.

Please help!

Here is some of the source code (part where Im getting the error)
Start Analysis

```
       self._logger.info("Parsing data files for GSEA.............................")
        # phenotype labels parsing
        cls_vector = self.load_classes()
        # select correct expression genes and values.
        dat, cls_dict = self.load_data(cls_vector)
        self.cls_dict = cls_dict
        # data frame must have length > 1
        assert len(dat) > 1
        # filtering out gene sets and build gene sets dictionary
        gmt = self.load_gmt(gene_list=dat.index.values, gmt=self.gene_sets)
        self.gmt = gmt
        self._logger.info(
            "%04d gene_sets used for further statistical testing....." % len(gmt)
        )
        self._logger.info("Start to run GSEA...Might take a while..................")
        # cpu numbers
        # compute ES, NES, pval, FDR, RES
        if self.permutation_type == "gene_set":
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my dataframe was an "object" instead of numbers so I was getting an empty dataframe for the computation. Solution was:

gsea_df_HDM = gsea_df_HDM.astype(float)